# Adding noise _on top_ of damped constraint?

Tags: constraints

I've created a cone and in the graph editor, I've added noise modifiers to the x, y and z rotations. So, the cone jiggles about a little bit on all axes.

I want the tip of the cone to track the camera, i.e. always point at it. So, I added a damped track constraint to the cone with the constraint target being the camera. However, when I do this the cone becomes locked on hard to the camera and I lose the noise effect on all axes (except the track axis of the constraint, the z-axis in my example).

How, can I get my cone to point at the camera while still allowing a bit of jiggle on all axes?

Here's the cone happily jiggling about on all axes before the constraint was added:
[image: jiggling on all axes]

After the constraint is added, the cone points directly at the camera as desired but now there's only jiggle on the z-axis:
[image: constrained cone]

Here's the `.blend` file (it's just 840kb):

[image]

Comment: Parent the cone to an empty.  Put the damped track on the empty parent.  Leave the noise on the cone.

Comment: OK - that was simpler than I expected! Worked - thank you. If you added it as an answer, I'd accept it.